# Which are reasons restart cassandra's cluster?

Tags: cassandra

I just have one reason to restart cluster below :

All the nodes have the same hardware configuration
 1. When i update file cassandra.yaml

Are there other reasons ?

Answer (score 2):

The thing you are asking for is **Rolling Restart** a `cassandra cluster`. There are so many reason to restart a `cassandra cluster`. I'm just mentioning some below-

1. when you update any value in `cassandra.yaml`. (As you mentioned above)
2. When your `nodetool` got stucked somehow. such as- you gave command `nodetool repair` and cancelled the command but it got stucked behind, then you won't be able to give another `nodetool repair` command.
3. When you are adding a new node to cluster and you got `stream_failed` due to `nproc` limit. That time your running cluster nodes could be down to this issue and going to hold the status.
4. When you don't want to use `sstableloader` and you need to restore your data from `snapshots`. That time you need to provide your `snapshots` to the `data_directory` on each node and rolling restart.
5. When you are about to upgrade your `cassandra_version`.

Comment: 4. You don't have to restart a cluster after recover the data from snapshots. you execute ./nodetool refresh keyspace table on evry nodes. [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_snapshot_restore_t.html) - use  the method Copy the snapshot SSTable directory.

Comment: I was talking about the "Node restart method", described here-https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_snapshot_restore_t.html#task_ds_vf4_z1r_gk

Answer (score 0):

For example when you upgrading Cassandra version.